# Select first ten elements using nth-of-type in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-selectors, lazy-loading

I'm trying to target the first ten images on my page which have a class of `.lazy`

I'm using [unveil](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) to lazy load images, it waits for a scroll to load images but you can trigger all images to load with this line:

`$("img").trigger("unveil");`

I want to trigger just the first 10 images to always show straightaway, so I've tried this:

```
$("#portfolio .portfolio-item img.lazy:nth-of-type(-n+10)").trigger("unveil");
```

In CSS `:nth-of-type(-n+10)` selects the first ten matching elements, but when I try this out on my console using this jQuery

```
$("img.lazy:nth-of-type(-n+10)")
```

..it returns every img with the class of `.lazy`

What am I doing wrong? is there a way to select the first ten instead using jQuery's `.eq`?

to give you some idea of my markup:

```
<div class="portfolio">
     <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="lazy" src="item-1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="lazy" src="item-2.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="lazy" src="item-3.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="lazy" src="item-4.jpg">
     </div>
     etc... (there 20 items in total)
</div>
```

is the issue that each img is nested within a separate parent?

Comment: Note that your selector has `#portfolio`, yet the element itself has that as a `class`.

Comment: ahh yeh I've got both a class and an id of portfolio on the actual markup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector to select first `n` elements.

> Select all elements at an `index` less than index within the matched set.

```
$("#portfolio .portfolio-item img.lazy:lt(10)").trigger("unveil");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/m82qwxxh/)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `slice()`. Slice is more powerful in a sense that you can apply properties between a range of elements

```
$("#portfolio .portfolio-item img.lazy").slice(0,10).trigger("unveil");
```

Here is a code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').slice(2, 5).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```